# My Category is too big on the Menu what can i do?

Tags: plugins, multisite, customization, categories

Currently I have a small amount of 100 categories and my MENU goes crazy big and I would like to be able to do 2 things if possible:

- First category menu with limited amount categories sorted by hits
- Second category menu with limited amount of categories choose by myself

Is there any simple way to acomplish this either manually editing part of the code but yet allowing me to render the category by the wordpress code instead of having to type each by hand or a plugin with already such features ?

PS: I was trying to use the search for this but even using "Category Menu too big" there were so many unrelated answer that it was hard to find anything good to my case.

Comment: *@Prix* - Which menu system are you using? The v3.0 `wp_nav_menu()` or the older `wp_list_page()`?  Can you provide more information about your actual implementation?

Comment: Default wp installation menu on the side bar the default category list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved away from looking for a plugin and adventured myself into making my own modifications, see [Custom sidebar category listing?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/custom-sidebar-category-listing)

In regards my question here I have found the follow:

- Yes, it is possible to limit the amount of items listed on the category by setting the number argument that can be used with [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) and [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).
- A personalized menu can be create with only the categories you wish to allow on it on the Menu that code can be re-used on the sidebar, only problem is that it will be manually updated/controlled.

Answer (score 1):

This...

- First category menu with limited amount categories sorted by hits
- Second category menu with limited amount of categories choose by myself

... is, I believe, impossible using the menu API.