# Custom sidebar category listing?

Tags: customization, categories

I am trying to make a custom Category Display on my side bar and for that I need some way to get both, the category list and the child list in 2 different arrays or something alike...

First, I tried the function `get_categories`, but it does not allow me to gather top-level categories only:

```
$args=array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC');
$categories=get_categories($args);
```

Then, I moved to `wp_list_categories` which does what I want. However, the return does not give me an array of data that I can query. It gives me a simple HTML-formatted list ready to print out:

```
$categories=wp_list_categories('echo=0&style=none&orderby=name&order=ASC&depth=1&title_li=');
```

- Is there a way to gather the top
  level categories list in a way I can
  personalize it as I wish ?

  For Example:

  ```
  foreach($category_list as $category) {
      echo ' <li>';
      echo '  <a title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->cat_name ) . '" href="' . get_category_link($category->cat_ID) . '">' . $category->cat_name . ' (' . $category->cat_ID .') </a>';
      echo '  <a onclick="s_toggleDisplay(document.getElementById(\'CHILD CATS\'), this, \'▼\', \'▲\');" href="javascript:void(null);">▼</a>';
      echo ' </li>';
  }
  ```

Why do I want the top-level only ? Because, I wanted to make a show/hide function for the children of the top-level category. If you have another way to accomplish this or suggestion, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip categories that have parent in your loop:

```
foreach($category_list as $category) {

if( '0' != $category->parent )
    continue;
```

I've looked through the source, but it seems `depth` is only taken in account in `wp_list_categories()` and you will probably need to extend `Walker_Category` class to custom walker there to make changes to output.

Actually, this might be a good idea if you need a really complex categories output format.

Comment: AWESOME you hitted the nail guess will check the source more often because the documents don't tell about the parent field being returned. thanks.